# How to unpack ID3 header's size

Tags: python, mp3, id3

I am trying to unpack the ID3v2.3 header with Python 2.7. However, I do not fully understand the first 10 bytes of the MP3 format. For example:

```
49 44 33 03 00 00 | 00 00 21 76 | 54 41 4C 42
.I .D .3 .3 .0    | RawSize     | Size
```

Using [Synalyze it!](https://www.synalysis.net) I can see that `RawSize` is `0x2176` and `Size` is `4342`.

At offset `4352` is where the MPEG data frames begin. I need to know how 
`54 41 4C 42` gets converted to `4342` because when I tried:

```
>>> unpack('i', '\x54\x41\x4C\x42')
(1112293716,)
```

which does not look in anyways like `4352`!

How should I read them in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you give 14 bytes there, not 10.

Secondly, you've botched reading the size completely. The size uses unpacked 7-bit values rather than 8-bit values.

```
>>> 0x00 << 21 | 0x00 << 14 | 0x21 << 7 | 0x76
4342
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how should `54 41 4C 42` be understood/parsed?

Comment: As a "TALB" tag.

Comment: Thank you @Ignacio